# C++: overloading list.end() and list.begin() methods for constant iterators

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator, overloading, c++builder

I'm still trying to implement my own version of LinkedList class and now I have problems with overloading methods for constant iterators. For example, when I try to print out list using this code:

```
cout << "citer:" << endl;
for (UberList<int>::CIter it = ulist.begin(); it != ulist.end(); ++it)
{
 cout << *it << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

I have these errors:

```
Error E2034 UberList2.cpp 532: Cannot convert 'UberList<int>::Iter' to 'UberList<int>::CIter' in function main()
Error E2094 UberList2.cpp 532: 'operator!=' not implemented in type 'UberList<int>::CIter' for arguments of type 'UberList<int>::Iter' in function main()
```

so as far as I understood, it means that those usual end and begin iterator methods are used. Here's how these methods are declared in my class:

```
Iter begin();
Iter end();
CIter begin() const;
CIter end() const;
```

and

```
template<class T>
typename UberList<T>::Iter UberList<T>::begin()
{
    Iter it;
    it.curr = head;
    return it;
}

template<class T>
typename UberList<T>::Iter UberList<T>::end()
{
 Iter it;
 it.curr = tail->next;
 return it;
}

template<class T>
typename UberList<T>::CIter UberList<T>::begin() const
{
 CIter it;
 it.ccurr = head;
 return it;
}

template<class T>
typename UberList<T>::CIter UberList<T>::end() const
{
 CIter it;
 it.ccurr = tail->next;
 return it;
}
```

Is there any way I can force my program to use these const methods for constant iterators instead of usual ones? I'd be glad to hear any advice.

Oh and here's the code of my class in one file just in case: http://pastebin.com/Jbvv5Hht

Comment: Your code looks ok, i've added some 'consts' in the operators in the pastebin. Probably will not help, but the code looks OK

Comment: Thank you, but I still get these errors =(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should provide a conversion from `Iter` to `CIter`. Standard containers do (Table 65, in 23.1 "Container requirements", says that `X::iterator` is convertible to `X::const_iterator`)

The caller can ensure that the `const` overload is called by using a `const` reference, but you shouldn't force them to do that, because they will have to write something like:

```
UberList<int>::CIter it = static_cast<const UberList<int> &>(ulist).begin()
```

If you provide the "required" conversion then there's no need for your caller to do anything special: your original code will work, just as it does for standard containers.

Comment: um but can I just force it to use begin and end methods that return CIter type and avoid conversion?

Comment: @Chris: do you mean "I" as in "I, the person writing the container", or "I" as in "the person writing the code that uses the container". Yes to the latter, no to the former. Why are you resistant to implementing the container interface used in the standard?

Comment: because I don't really know how I can implement conversion. I made a constructor for CIter that receives Iter and imports link from Iter to CIter and tried to make = for and != for CIter - Iter operators, but I still get same error messages

Comment: @Chris: fine time to learn ;-) Your `CIter` constructor as written ought to be sufficient to provide the conversion, and you shouldn't then need to implement any operators that mix CIter and Iter, because in all mixed cases the Iter can be converted to CIter. To compile your code from pastebin I had to (1) add a forward declaration of Iter before CIter; (2) remove the broken `operator=` at line 173; (3) change the postincrement at line 452 to a preincrement. Then it compiled without errors, although eventually it needs a proper `operator=`, and iterators ought to have a postincrement too.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: aah I'd be very grateful if you share this edited code =)

Comment: @Chris: http://pastebin.com/J7hjndsD. I still get a warning from GCC: the `erase` function doesn't return a value in all cases, but I didn't touch that because it doesn't prevent compilation.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: thank you very much ^^ it works just as I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Some more comments to the OP's code. Consider separating that gigantic uberl33tlist class and break it up into smaller files. Seeing all those friends class declaration is making me rather uncomfortable. There are also some tricky semantics When you're using stuff like

```
friend class UberList;
friend class CIter;
```

In some cases those statements also end up *forward declaring* those classes if they don't exist yet. There's also something not quite right looking about your assignment operator here:

```
UberList<T> operator = (const UberList<T>& OL)
{
    UberList<T> NL = new (OL);
    return NL;
}
```

Also in your main you have

```
it2++;
ulist.insertAfter(b, it2);
//...
```

You're using postfix operator ++ for it2 but didn't implement that your iterator class. Borland accepts it by using the prefix instead but gives a warning. Gcc actually flags that as an error and rejects the code. Might want to look into that

Answer (score 1):

Sigh: there's a level of hackery here designed to hide the fact that conceptually what you want to do cannot be done automatically in C++ because it doesn't understand variance. Some other languages (including Ocaml) do.

If you have a functor (that's a template class to C++ programmers), the question is how it and various functions behave with a variance of the parameter, such as a conversion from T to T const. What you really want is this:

```
List<T> --> List<T const>
```

in other words you want the List functor to be covariant. But no, it isn't .. so actually the List template isn't a functor at all, because functors must be structure preserving and the conversion isn't reflected as required. In turn this means either C++ templates are broken OR the concept of const is broken, because a type system that doesn't support parametric polymorhism is broken by specification :)

Providing "const_iterator" does not solve this problem, it simply patches up the break. Where is the volatile and const_volatile version? How about double indirections?

If you don't understand double indirections: consider a tree of vectors of T, that's two templates:

```
Tree<Vector<T>>
```

The best solution here is to give up supporting const_iterator. Just don't bother. It's confused anyhow: how about "const vector"? What's that? A vector you can't make longer but it still allows you to write the elements?

The actual requirement is that transforms commute, for example:

```
vector<T> const == vector<T const>
```

[or they anti-commute if the transform is contra-variant]

The fact this doesn't happen shows that vector isn't functorial, in other words, templates can't be used effectively for parametric polymorphism. If you want to really get your knickers tied in a knot consider templates with function arguments and ask about the variance of the function's return type and parameters, and how this might impact the container. A good example is how to compose a two functions so they work on a pair. What if they're mutators, how does "const" work then?

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
teamplate<class T> bool operator!=(UberList<T>::CIter,UberList<T>::CIter);
```

Comment: But it should be: this is what the compiler complains about in the second error message.

Answer (score -2):

It's using the regular begin method because the variable is not const. So one way of fixing it is to make another (reference) variable that is const:

```
UberList<int> const & culist = ulist;
for (UberList<int>::Citer it = culist.begin(); ...)
```

Alternatively, use a const_cast.

Comment: You don't need (and shouldn't use) a `const_cast` to add const.

Comment: Of course you should use const_cast to add const. That's the whole point. If you use static_cast instead, you may undesirably perform the wrong cast. With a const_cast, there is a compiler check that the only conversion you perform is addition or removal of const (or volatile).

Comment: The "whole point" of `const_cast` is that it's the only cast that can remove const. But OK, I guess that if there exist other types that your container can be converted to, a compiler check that you aren't converting to one of those is theoretically useful. Of course as you say, using a const_cast might mean you accidentally remove volatile at the same time as adding const, which is probably the main reason specifically *not* to use const_cast to add const. Depends which error you'd prefer the compiler to catch.

Comment: eer that const_cast stuff sounds too complicated for me

Comment: But aside from that, I prefer `const_cast` to be a "here be dragons" warning, and it doesn't serve that purpose if you use it for safe operations too. That's probably just a style issue, though, so "shouldn't" is perhaps overstating my case on those grounds. Safest I guess is to rely only on implicit conversion (well, reference-binding), as in your code snippet, even if that prevents one-liners.

Comment: @Christ: then declare the second variable. This will avoid any conversion issues.